# Run MSSQL JDBC Example on CentOS java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, centos

I'm trying to run an example of the JDBC Microsoft SQL Connection described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg715284.aspx)

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestAzure {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      try {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
      }

      // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
      catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally {
         if (rs != null) try { rs.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
         if (stmt != null) try { stmt.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
         if (con != null) try { con.close(); } catch(Exception e) {}
      }
   }
}
```

Unfortunately this fails:

```
overlord@overlord-datanode1:~/Documents/hadoop/scripts/03_azure_sql$ java TestAzure -cp ./
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
        at TestAzure.main(TestAzure.java:18)
```

I tried to find a solution in the [description of the JDBC driver here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx).

I used -cp ./ to set the classpath to the local directory.
I also tried this suggestion "It looks like you need to add the jar to the classpath - eg "java TestAzure -cp ./:./sqljdbc4.jar"

The sqljdbc4.jar is in the same folder + I checked that the class is inside:

```
overlord@overlord-datanode1:~/Documents/hadoop/scripts/03_azure_sql$ jar tf sqljdbc4.jar | grep SQLServerDriver
com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver.class
com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriverPropertyInfo.class
```

Why is the class not found?

Comment: `java -cp .:./sqljdbc4.jar TestAzure` It will be a classpath problem. With a jdbc4 driver, you shouldn't even need to do a `Class.forName` anymore since the driver will register automatically if it is on the classpath.